# Strange problems with ranging a beacon region while monitoring the same beacon region in the same time on iPhone 5S

Tags: ios, bluetooth, monitoring, core-location, ibeacon

We are experiencing some strange problems with ranging and monitoring the same beacon region in the same time on iPhone 5S. These problems are not experienced on an iPhone XR so we suspect that it could be some kind of iOS issue on iPhone 5S.

iOS: 12.4.1
Device: iPhone 5S
Xcode: 10.3
Deployment target set to: 12.4
Code: Objective C

**Description / steps of the problem:**

- In a really simple test application we start monitoring and ranging a beacon region (with 2 beacons in proximity) in the same time (code snippet attached below)
- We are logging the beacons found by the ranging process (in didRangeBeacons)
- The app shows that 2 beacons are detected
- Move the app in background, wait a little bit, and bring it into foreground again
- The app will show only one beacon (the other one is lost)

**Notes:**

- When our test app detects only 1 beacon instead of 2 beacons, then any other apps on that iPhone 5S that uses ranging will detect just one beacon (this is why we suspect that it should be an iOS issue)
- If that beacon region contains only 1 beacon then I can reproduce that issue only if I stop and restart the beacon in the proximity of the iPhone (the ranging process will not see it again). With 2 or more beacons it is reproducible even if the app is moved to background and brought into foreground again as noted above.
- Sometimes if I close the screen of the iPhone and re-open it then the lost beacon will re-appear for a moment but it will disappear again
- If 'startMonitoringForRegion' is commented out in the code then everything works fine
- The above issues are not reproducible on an iPhone XR

Did somebody experienced the above issues and have a good workaround for them? Thank you very much  in advance.

---

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController () <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;
    self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

    CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"C336AA38-54BB-483B-AE75-3BA707855035"] identifier:@"test"];

    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region {

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray<CLBeacon *> *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"%@",beacons);
}

@end
```

**More info:**

I'm simulating the 2 beacons, one from an iPad (Noteacon app) and one from a Mac Book Pro (mbeacon tool).

When I start the test app, the beacons show up like this:

```
(
    "CLBeacon (uuid:C336AA38-54BB-483B-AE75-3BA707855035, major:100, minor:101, proximity:2 +/- 1.29m, rssi:-61)",
    "CLBeacon (uuid:C336AA38-54BB-483B-AE75-3BA707855035, major:100, minor:102, proximity:2 +/- 2.78m, rssi:-63)"
)
```

When I move the app to background and bring it back to foreground they will show up like this, one with rssi = 0 for a few seconds and after that it disappears:

```
(
    "CLBeacon (uuid:C336AA38-54BB-483B-AE75-3BA707855035, major:100, minor:102, proximity:0 +/- -1.00m, rssi:0)",
    "CLBeacon (uuid:C336AA38-54BB-483B-AE75-3BA707855035, major:100, minor:101, proximity:2 +/- 1.43m, rssi:-62)"
)

(
    "CLBeacon (uuid:C336AA38-54BB-483B-AE75-3BA707855035, major:100, minor:101, proximity:2 +/- 1.44m, rssi:-62)"
)
```

'didExitRegion' is not called in this case, as I still have a beacon in range.

For the second problem, when I have only one beacon, I stop / restart the beacon and it will disappear from the app, and I am not getting the 'didExitRegion' call (I waited several minutes for it). When I close the screen of the phone and reopen it with the app in foreground, usually the beacon re-appers (but sometimes just reappears for a several seconds and disappears again). When a beacon disappears from my app then it will not show up in any apps that ranges beacons (like Locate Beacons app). If I delete my app or comment out the `startMonitoringForRegion` call then the above problems are not happening and everything works fine.

The interesting thing is that everything works fine on an iPhone XR and couldn't reproduce any of the above problems on it. Only on my iPhone 5S.

Comment: You said the app **shows** one beacon. How do you check this in your code? Do you check it in `didRangeBeacons` function?

Comment: Yes, I'm checking it in the `didRangeBeacons` with that `NSLog(@"%@",beacons);`

Comment: What are the identifiers of the two beacons -- are they different?  Are these off the shelf beacons or something custom?  You say, "If that beacon region contains only 1 beacon then I can reproduce that issue only if I stop and restart the beacon in the proximity of the iPhone (the ranging process will not see it again)." In this case, do you get a didExitRegion call?

Comment: Also, can you reproduce the problem with an off the shelf app like [Locate Beacon](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014)?   (It also ranges and monitors simultaneously.)

Comment: I edited my original post with the answers (see More info section). It was too long to add here just as a comment. Hmmm ... but I can reproduce now my problem with the Locate Beacon app as well, so very probably that it should be some kind of iOS issue. I didn't know that Locate Beacons also monitors the beacons. I had to change the 'While Using the App' location authorisation into 'Always' for it and I can reproduce my problem with that app as well.

Comment: Not sure which devices are affected, if it is happening only on iPhone 5S or only on some of them, or it can happen on other iPhone models too...